# I'm finding String::copy rather difficult: copy first five characters of a string

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to teach myself to program, so I apologize in advance for any shoddy code or bad practices. Basically, I'm trying to copy part of a long string using string::copy, but I'm clearly not doing something right. My goal here is to copy and print the first five characters of the string "bignumber":

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     const string bignumber = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\
                               96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\
                               85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\
                               12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\
                               6689664895044524452316173185640309871121722383113\
                               62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\
                               30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\
                               70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
                               65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
                               52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
                               53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
                               83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
                               82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
                               16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\
                               17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\
                               24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\
                               07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\
                               84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\
                               05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\
                               71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

   int iter = 0;
   size_t window;
   char buffer[5];
   window = bignumber.copy(buffer,iter,iter+5);

   cout << window << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

This is for project Euler problem 8 if you care. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "I'm trying to teach myself to program" >>> Not to discourage, but you would be much happier in a high level language (for now), like python, php, ruby, .net, etc...

Answer (score 3):

I believe you misread the documentation of `basic_string::copy`. From [this page](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/basic_string/copy) :

> ```
> size_type copy( Char* s, size_type count, size_type index = 0 ) const;
> ```
>
> Copies count characters from the position, starting at index to the given character string s. The resulting string is not NULL terminated.

Your use of the first parameter is correct (`buffer` being a char array, it will decay to a char pointer upon function argument passing), but your second and third arguments aren't :

- `size_type count` is the number of characters to copy : you are providing 0 while you seem to want 5
- `size_type index` is the starting index for character copying : you are providing 5 while you apparently need 0 (copy `count` characters from the start of the string). The parameter happens to have a default argument value of 0 : you don't have to provide any value here.

In the end, you could do :

```
const size_t window = bignumber.copy(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

Notice that I've used `sizeof(buffer)` rather than the magic value 5 to avoid introducing a bug if the `buffer` size is changed without reflecting the modification to this call. Also be aware that `buffer` cannot be simply outputted to `std::cout` after the call to `copy` because it is not a null terminated string.

---

Now, if working with `std::string` only is an option (and in most cases, it should be), you might as well be using [`basic_string::substr`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/basic_string/substr) :

> ```
> basic_string substr( size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos ) const;
> ```
>
> Returns a substring of the current string, starting at the given position index and having length of count characters.

For example :

```
const std::string substring = bignumber.substr(0, 5);
```

Contrary to the `copy` solution, there is no possible size issue here, and the result can be outputted to `std::cout` without any problem. In other words : it's much safer.

Answer (score 0):

The substr member function would be the more conventional solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check into that.